# How can I find out size of a local file using flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, action

I am trying to create an uploader in flash, To do so I have to find out size of the file before uploading to the server, How can I find out this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FileReference.size](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#size).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a PHP script that you could call before attempting to load the file
the script would return the filesize which you would retrieve with Actionscript

PHP function filesize()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

check the URLVariables class
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/